# How can I properly request.POST of a form with one-to-one relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm still getting an error "ModelForm has no model class specified." although I already specified the model in class Meta in DetailForm.
How can I properly request.POST of a form with one-to-one relationship?

```
#model.py
    class Component(models.Model):
        partnumber = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        maker = models.ForeignKey(Maker, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)
    
    class Description(models.Model):
        component = models.ForeignKey(Component, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='descriptions')
        text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.text
    
    #form.py
    class ComponentForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Component
            fields=['partnumber','maker', 'description']
    
    class DetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            models = Detail
            fields=['modelseries']
    
    #form.py
    @login_required
    def edit(request,id):
        #Get the current component to edit
        comp = Component.objects.get(pk=id)
        comp_detail = comp.detail
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            c_form = ComponentForm(request.POST, instance=comp)
            cd_form = DetailForm(instance=comp_detail)
            if c_form.is_valid and cd_form.is_valid:
                c_form.instance.author = request.user
                c_form.save()
                messages.success(request, f'Component has been updated!')
                return redirect('component-index')
        else:
            c_form = ComponentForm(instance=comp)
            cd_form = DetailForm(instance=comp_detail)
           
        context ={
            'c_form':c_form,
            'cd_form':cd_form
        }
        return render(request, 'component/edit.html',context)
```

Comment: It seems to be typo, you wrote `models = Detail` it should be `model = Detail` also in this fields there is no Detail model Class

Comment: Thank you! Sorry my mistake, should have check the typo error properly. Solved!

Comment: these kind of things always happen after long days of coding. glad I could help